# Unity Android - Error deserializing JSON credential data - Google STT API

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-speech-to-text-api

I boiled down the problem to the `SpeechClientBuilder` class's function `.Build()` after setting up credentials which I know are 100% right cause I checked and they worked when running the code on the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Edit` > `Project Settings` > `Player` > `Other Settings` > `Api Comppatibility Level` and set it to `.Net 4.x`. This fixed this problem